# Break string into list elements based on keywords

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a function (in Python) that takes its input (a chemical formula) and splits in into a list. 
For example, if the input was "HC2H3O2", it would turn it into:

```
molecule_list = ['H', 1, 'C', 2, 'H', 3, 'O', 2]
```

This, works well so far, but if I input an element with two letters in it, for example sodium (Na), it would split it into:

```
['N', 'a']
```

I'm searching for a way to make my function look through the string for keys found in a dictionary called elements. I'm also considering using regex for this, but I'm not sure how to implement it. This is what my function is right now:

```
def split_molecule(inputted_molecule):
    """Take the input and split it into a list
    eg: C02 => ['C', 1, 'O', 2]
    """
    # step 1: convert inputted_molecule to a list
    # step 2a: if there are two periodic elements next to each other, insert a '1'
    # step 2b: if the last element is an element, append a '1'
    # step 3: convert all numbers in list to ints

    # step 1:
    # problem: it splits Na into 'N', 'a'
    # it needs to split by periodic elements
    molecule_list = list(inputted_molecule)

    # because at most, the list can double when "1" is inserted
    max_length_of_molecule_list = 2*len(molecule_list)
    # step 2a:
    for i in range(0, max_length_of_molecule_list):
        try:
            if (molecule_list[i] in elements) and (molecule_list[i+1] in elements):
                molecule_list.insert(i+1, "1")
        except IndexError:
            break
    # step2b:     
    if (molecule_list[-1] in elements):
        molecule_list.append("1")

    # step 3:
    for i in range(0, len(molecule_list)):
        if molecule_list[i].isdigit():
            molecule_list[i] = int(molecule_list[i])

    return molecule_list
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
import re
print re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]?|[0-9]+', 'Na2SO4MnO4')
```

result

```
['Na', '2', 'S', 'O', '4', 'Mn', 'O', '4']
```

Regex explained:

```
Find everything that is either

    [A-Z]   # A,B,...Z, ie. an uppercase letter
    [a-z]   # followed by a,b,...z, ie. a lowercase latter
    ?       # which is optional
    |       # or
    [0-9]   # 0,1,2...9, ie a digit
    +       # and perhaps some more of them
```

This expression is pretty dumb since it accepts arbitrary "elements", like "Xy". You can improve it by replacing the `[A-Z][a-z]?` part with the actual list of elements' names, separated by `|`, like `Ba|Na|Mn...|C|O`

Of course, regular expressions can only handle very simple formulas, to parse something like

```
  8(NH4)3P4Mo12O40 + 64NaNO3 + 149NH4NO3 + 135H2O
```

you're going to need a real parser, e.g. [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) (be sure to check "chemical formulas" under "Examples"). Good luck!

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you! Would you mind explaining the regex?

Comment: +1 for mentioning that you would need a real parser, instead of a regex parser

Answer (score 2):

An expression like this will match all parts of interest:

```
[A-Z][a-z]*|\d+
```

You can use it with `re.findall` and then add the quantifier for atoms that have none.

Or you could use a regex for that as well:

```
molecule = 'NaHC2H3O2'
print re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*|\d+', re.sub('[A-Z][a-z]*(?![\da-z])', r'\g<0>1', molecule))
```

Output:

```
['Na', '1', 'H', '1', 'C', '2', 'H', '3', 'O', '2']
```

The `sub` adds a `1` after all atoms not followed by a number.

Answer (score 1):

The non-regex approach, which is a bit hackish and probably not the best, but it works:

```
import string

formula = 'HC2H3O2Na'
m_list = list()
for x in formula:
   if x in string.lowercase:
      m_list.append(formula[formula.index(x)-1]+x)
      _ = m_list.pop(len(m_list)-2)
   else:
      m_list.append(x)
print m_list
['H', 'C', '2', 'H', '3', 'O', '2', 'Na']
```